# Can you use SvelteJS without NodeJs?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Sorry I'm new to this. I have a new project that will use SvelteJS but the problem is the deployment server does not have nodejs server installed for administrative reason. So is there a way to use Svelte in my web app like VueJs where you have an option to use cdn only? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Basically Svelte is for SPA (single page application) like vue or react. So a bundle in a html file is ok. It can work locally. No need for a server. And you can upload your SPA to a web server, which is just sending the html/css/js.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at sapper: https://sapper.svelte.dev/

You can use sapper export to generate a static svelte based website.

Comment: Sapper doesn't exist anymore, it seems to have been included in SvelteKit...

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to Plenti go web server: https://github.com/plentico/plenti

But Plenti has no built-in server script engine.

The Algernon go web server has built-it Lua script support, but it has no built-in svelte compiler: https://github.com/xyproto/algernon/issues/125